# Logging on to CAS server through cURL

Tags: curl, cas

I am trying to login to a CAS server using cURL.  Here is where I am so far.

I grabbed the authentication page and replaced POST with GET to see what my fields are.

> file:///cas/login;jsessionid=89C2DA1B80B0C4E812F2D09CC01C05DB?username=&password=&lt=LT-2960-zIS6pxYZHdsBX7IkykfbW14oLJhdNL&execution=e1s1&_eventId=submit&submit=LOGIN

so I run

```
curl -k --cookie-jar dump --data "jsessionid=89C2DA1B80B0C4E812F2D09CC01C05DB?username=&password=&lt=LT-2960-zIS6pxYZHdsBX7IkykfbW14oLJhdNL&execution=e1s1&_eventId=submit&submit=LOGIN" https://CASHOST/cas/login > output
```

(filling out the username, password, and CASHOST obviously)

But my output is blank.  If I remove the jsessionid field its also blank.

Something that is worrying me is the jsessionid field because its constantly changing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I realize its not that simple..  but I found a resource that points me in a good direction.  [link](https://gist.github.com/dodok1/4134605)  Only problem is on the step with the header dump.  There's no "Location" field in the header.  Is anyone else able to replicate the script correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use curl -v.
Probably you are getting 302 redirect to the login page.

I am using adopted 
https://gist.github.com/dodok1/4134605
which works fine for me, and maybe will work better for you.

All it needed was to add &execution=e1s1
to the call which passes the password to CAS.

My working solution is here: https://gist.github.com/gkazior/4cf7e4c38fbcbc310267

Comment: I tried to add the &execution as well, but it appears there's a problem with the third curl.  I added -v to the curl commands but I get `curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information` as output for the second one.  Specifically, there's no `Location:` in my header dump.  `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 Feb 2015 17:03:43 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 6179
Connection: close`  

Up until this point everything seems fine.

Comment: Well, the script supports the happy path only, so something went wrong in the middle. Try to run the script like that 

sh -x cas-get.sh 

When your service is not granted then you wont get login ticket LT*. When your password is not OK then .cookieJar does not contains TGT* ticket.

https://gist.github.com/gkazior/4cf7e4c38fbcbc310267 now prints problem and exits.

Comment: Interesting.  So I get to the same point, but with your error message `Cannot login. Check if you can login in a browser using...` so I tried going to the CASAUTH url with the redirect and typing in my username and password, but it redirects me to a page that says `Application Not Authorized to Use CAS
The application you attempted to authenticate to is not authorized to use CAS.` Now this is from the web browser.  It appears like it is not handling the ?service=httpetcetc redirect. If I remove the ?service=httpetcetc and go to the CASAUTH/cas/login url it says `Sign In Successful`

Comment: It appears that when I type in the url I intend to go in the web browser I get redirected to the CASAUTH/cas/login?service="URL" but the "URL" is not the place I intended to go to.  It looks like another authentication mechanism perhaps..

Comment: It looks like this: `https://CASAUTH/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fssomgr.EDUADDRESS%3A443%2Fssomanager%2Fc%2FSSB%3Fret_code%3D`

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add `-L` to make curl follow the redirect to `CURL_DEST`